# Filtering Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame Based on Level Counts

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex Pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
a       e       m
b       f       n
        g       o
c       h       p
        i       q
d       j       r
        k       s
        l       t
```

The MultiIndex consists of `col1` and `col2`.

How can I select the "rows" of `col1` which hold exactly two index labels in `col2`?

I.e., I want:

```
col1    col2    col3
b       f       n
        g       o
c       h       p
        i       q
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the group by [**`filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)

```
df.groupby('col1').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)

          col3
col1 col2     
b    f       n
     g       o
c    h       p
     i       q
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
s=df.groupby(level=0).size()

df.loc[s[s==2].index.tolist()]
Out[583]: 
          col3
col1 col2     
b    f       n
     g       o
c    h       p
     i       q
```